# Listview in full screen flutter

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I'm writing an app in flutter, and I was faced with a problem.All items are at the top.As I found out this is a problem with a listview which is not stretched to full screen.How to stretch a listview in full screen?

Comment: Can you include the code-snippet? more about [minimal-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0):

can you please share the code so that we can solve it..

and from your Question it's sounds like you need to wrap your listview in a sized box and give it height and with which you want..
for Example:

```
SizedBox(
   height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height, // this will get the height of your screen
   width:  MediaQuery.of(context).size.width, // this will get the width of your screen
   child: ListView(
      children:[
         // your widgets
   ],
  ),
),
```